# Getting all foreign keys corresponding to a table and the tables that hold those foreign keys with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I need to get all the foreign keys of a particular table and get the names of the tables containing those foreign keys, is there a simple way to do this using `JDBC`?

I know there is a way to do this for a particular database using a query, but I need to get a generic solution using `JDBC`.

Comment: probably duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716651/get-all-foreign-keys-using-jdbc

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for, getImportedKeys gets you the foreign keys in that particular table, what I'm looking for are the foreign keys inside other tables referencing a field in my original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`DatabaseMetaData.getExportedKeys`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

> Retrieves a description of the foreign key columns that reference the given table's primary key columns (the foreign keys exported by a table).

For example

```
dbmd.getExportedKeys(null, null, "SOME_TABLE_NAME")
```

will return a list of all tables and their foreign keys pointing to the primary key of `SOME_TABLE_NAME`.